# hunting aliens probability brainteaser

Tags: probability, recreational-mathematics

The deep space researcher John Smith would like to determine the unknown number $n$ of alien species in the neighbourhood of Ursa Minor. 
John assumes that all $n$ species are abundant and encountered with equal probabilities.

His spaceship has four cells for aliens. During the hunting trip John has caught two squidoraptors, one lizardog and one unicorn tiger.

For which value of $n$ the probability of hunting these aliens would be maximal?

Comment: So the cells are full.  Did he encounter any others and leave them alone?

Comment: @Henry I think the number of cells is just another way of saying the number of encounters. The hunter concluded his trip as soon as the 4th encounter was made. The related fact that all the species are abundant means all encounters are independent and the order doesn't matter.

Comment: @Henry, John concluded the trip as soon as the cells were full :)

Comment: So you need to start by finding the probability that John would capture those creatures given there are  $n$ species (or at least something proportional to that probability)

Comment: @Henry, I have two solutions :) I just propose this brainteaser for you and everyone interested in probability. I have googled and it seems that the brainteaser is unknown. It was born as an exam problem for maximum likelihood and most students got it wrong :)

Comment: Seeing the useful information as $3$ unique species from a sample size $4$ with replacement, [I would say](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/9261/2958) then in terms of $n$ the likelihood is proportional to $\dfrac{n!}{(n-3)!\,n^4}$.  That is maximised when $n=5$

Comment: @Henry, exactly. I would accept it as a correct answer :)